# Is there a better function to approximate $\pi(x)$ other than the logarithm integral function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I've read somewhere (I could be wrong) that Chebyshev proved that $\int_2^x dt/\ln t$ is a better approximation to $\pi(x)$ than any algebraic combination of $x$ and $\ln x$. Is the logarithm integral function the best approximation to the prime counting function? If this is the case is there a proof of this? Or there is a proof that this is false?

Comment: Have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30506/is-lix-the-best-possible-approximation-to-the-prime-counting-function

Comment: This approximation is already so good that it is not really worth to make an effort to further improve it , although this is of course possible , but only with much more complicated formulas.